# Nodejs Lambda s3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

i am trying to a write simple Node JS function,

step 1) which reads an image from s3 bucket

step 2) write the image to a file

step 3) read the file

step 4) write the image to s3 bucket.

This is part of my  actual work. I am really struck with this task. Could you please help me to finish this.

Comment: It will make it much easier for people to help you if show what you've done so far and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some code [here](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/blob/master/README.md) you should be able to do this easily by copying code and inserting your values